# Clone a container control and its child controls during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms container control (e.g. a group box or a panel) with some child controls. Now I want to copy/clone this container control, so that I get a exact copy of it during runtime. How can I achieve this with C#?

What I want to do it something like this:

```
GroupBox groupNewBox;
groupBox1.CloneTo(groupNewBox);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi
The only way for copying an object is to implement IClonable interface. But as far as I know, windows controls do not implement this interface, So you should create your own conrtols derived from the container and child control which will implement [IClonable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface.

Answer (score -1):

implement ICloneable with the function like this:

```
public class NewClass, ICloneable
{


    public object Clone()
            {
                return MemberwiseClone();
            }

}
```